# Perfect Numbers bug?

Tags: c, debugging, math, for-loop, numbers

Currently I have this code, and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isFactor(long number1, long number2)
{
  int isitFactor = (number2 % number1 == 0)?1:0;
  return isitFactor;
}

int isPerfect(int number)
{
   int counter;
   int sum;
   for (counter = 1; counter < number; counter++) 
      if (isFactor(counter, number)) 
         sum += counter;
   return (sum == number);
}

int main()
{
   int counter = 1;
   for (counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
   {
      printf("", isPerfect(counter));
      if (isPerfect(counter)) 
         printf("%d\n", counter);
   }
}
```

However, if I take out the unnecessary line with the printf in main(), it fails to produce any numbers.... Possible causes?!

Comment: "Probable causes?": not enabling compiler warnings for use of an uninitialized variable, or ignoring such warnings if you did receive them.

Comment: how do i enable those warnings on gcc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Variable `sum` in function `isPerfect` is not initialized.

Comment: @tekknolagi printf probably zeros the stack location where sum happens to end up.

Answer (score 6):

You had two problems with that code, the first is that `sum` is not initialised and will generally be set to whatever rubbish happened to be on the stack at the time the function was called. Automatic variables are *not* guaranteed to be initialised to zero (or anything, for that matter) so, if you need them to start with a specific value, you have to initialise them yourself.

The second problem (now fixed with your edit) was that `isFactor` is missing. Although you probably want it as a function, the following code works, producing the two perfect numbers less than 100, `6` and `28`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define isFactor(c,n) ((n % c) == 0)

int isPerfect (int number) {
    int counter;
    int sum = 0;  // <-- note initialisation here.
    for (counter = 1; counter < number; counter++)
        if (isFactor(counter, number)) sum += counter;
    return (sum == number);
}

int main (void) {  // try to use one of the two canonical forms.
    int counter = 1;
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
        if (isPerfect(counter)) printf("%d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

---

And, looking into why it might be working with that extra `printf`, here's a viable explanation.

When calling a function, the local variables are allocated on the stack simply by reducing the stack pointer. Your `isPerfect` asembly code probably just has a prolog like:

```
sub %esp,8
```

and then you use the memory at %esp for `counter` and `%esp + 4` for sum. Without initialising `sum`, it starts with whatever happened to be at that memory location, which is probably not zero.

Now think about what happens when you call `printf` first. It no doubt has its own local variables so it uses the part of the stack that you will later be relying on to be initialised to zero. When the `printf` returns, it doesn't set those memory locations back to their previous values, it just increments the stack pointer to skip over them.

Then, when you call `isPerfect`, there's a good chance that those memory locations will be different to what they were before you called `printf`, simply because `printf` has been using them for its own purposes.

If you're lucky (or unlucky, depending on your viewpoint), the memory location where `sum` will be may even be zero. But it's undefined behaviour nonetheless and you should *not* rely on it - initialise `sum` explicitly and your (immediate) problems will be over.

---

If this is homework, feel free to ignore this bit (in fact, *actively* ignore it since you may get caught out for plagiarism). This is how I would implement the `isPerfect` function as a first cut. It doesn't call functions to work out factors since, while they're generally quite fast, they're not without cost, and something that simple can be done in a single line of C anyway.

```
int isPerfect (int num) {
  int i, left;
  for (i = 1, left = num; i < num; i++)
    if ((num % i) == 0)
      left -= i;
  return (left == 0);
}
```

There's no doubt it *could* be made faster but the return on investment drops away pretty quickly after a certain point.

Comment: Your macro is dangerous. It should be `(((n) % (c)) == 0)`

Comment: @Jim. macro functions are _inherently_ dangerous, I was just providing that as a sample. But, the way I'd write it would include macros or probably even a function for checking a factor - see the final bit.

Comment: @paxdiablo C'mon ... that macro is only dangerous the way you wrote it. Parenthesizing parameters is common practice to avoid the danger inherent in not doing so. How you would or wouldn't write it is irrelevant, only how you wrote it, which serves as a bad example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in my earler comment, _wouldn't_ include macros rather than _would._ And, if you don't like it, @Jim, downvote it. It's irrelevant to the question at hand since I explicitly stated you'd be better off with a function but your vote is your vote to cast as you see fit. Macros _are_ inherently dangerous but that can be mitigated by usage. Provided you use a single variable, my version is fine. And even parenthesised versions won't protect you from everything (double usage of a single `n--` parameter within a macro for example).

Comment: @paxdiablo I simply said it's dangerous and pointed out an improvement. I'm not going to waste my time on intellectual dishonesty. Neither parameter gets used more than once in _that_ macro, which is what I explicitly referred to.

Comment: Well, since you're limiting yourself to that macro, I can equally limit myself to that bit of code. And no call to that macro uses _anything_ that needs parentheses - they're all simple variables, no formulae or anything. I fully recognise that macros are dangerous and rarely use them but, if you call me for supposed intellectual dishonesty, I'm _going_ to defend myself. The _earliest_ version of my answer stated that you should probably use a function and that I was just adding in a macro since it wasn't provided in the original question.

Comment: I think we should probably leave it there. Have the last word if you wish, I will not respond since it detracts from the actual question and answer.

Comment: @Jim, @paxdiabolo: As we can see from the original question local variables are as dangerous as macros. If you use them wrong (here uninitialized), you easily get UB. But I never heard of someone claiming that you should avoid using local variables in C :)

Comment: I would not hire anyone who wrote a macro such as paxdiablo's, and I would fire anyone who defended writing one the way he has.

Comment: "if you call me for supposed intellectual dishonesty, I'm going to defend myself" -- The nature of the defense validates the charge. A simple edit would have made the point moot.

Comment: That's funny coming from you.